# User deleting code after question has been answered

Tags: discussion

If a user keeps [deleting the code from their question after receiving an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7682040/232610) (thus making the answer meaningless), what should we do? Rollback the edit (what if the user just deletes the code again)? Delete the question?

More examples (same user): [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643837/matlab-function-solving-an-error), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667143/matlab-error-message-function-definitions) (see also edit histories).

Comment: We've been getting a few of those in [tag:matlab] recently. [Here's another recent example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667654/suppressing-output-matlab) from a different user.

Comment: @yoda: I think it's the same user - at least the code is the same.

Comment: aha! Yes, definitely him.

Comment: I'm not even sure why somone would do this.

Comment: Lol, probably someone cheating on homework who's paranoid about getting caught.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rollback the edit. If the user deletes the code again, flag for a moderator and they can lock the question if neccessary.