# Dealing with question blanking

Tags: discussion, vandalism

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2229040/user2229040) has two questions. After he got the answer he needed on these questions, he replaced the text of each question with

> question deleted question deleted

(e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15728613/4)

Answers to both questions were upvoted, and so the OP would not have been able to delete the question. The user clearly wants to get rid of the question (e.g. fear of embarrassment).

What should be done in this circumstance? Should we vote to delete the question, because the user wills it and because (in at least one case) the question was poor? Should we revert the blanking, notify the user, and hope he doesn't try to blank it again? Should we try to edit the original question into shape so the user won't be motivated to remove it?

Comment: You engage in a rollback war until the OP either stops, or a mod locks it. :)

Comment: Usually you yell at the OP first. If the rollback war continues, an automatic flag will be raised.

Comment: possible duplicate of [User deleting code after question has been answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108617/user-deleting-code-after-question-has-been-answered), [What to do when the OP mutilates their own question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114803/what-to-do-when-the-op-mutilates-their-own-question/), [Proper way to deal with users removing question content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153118), [How should we treat posts that are vandalized by their original authors?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106807)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rollback the question to its previous state. Blanking questions is ugly and makes them useless.

If a user wants to delete a question, they can use the delete button. If they don't know about the delete button, they can search the FAQ for an answer.

But, if any user makes any harmful edit to any question, that edit should be rolled back. If you feel obligated to, leave a comment to inform the user about the delete button.

Note: Even if the question cannot be deleted because it has upvoted answers, it should be rolled back to its correct state. If a user really wants a question deleted, they can flag it for moderator attention (and you can let them know that is the correct avenue). But, the justification for not deleting upvoted questions is that they were valuable to someone, so their deletion is obviously discouraged.

Comment: Usually the reason why a user will blank a question is because the user is unable to delete it due to it having upvoted answers.

Comment: Great answer (sorry, fresh out of votes). This is all true. The only thing I would add is that you should *not* enter into a rollback war with someone. Roll it back once and maybe a leave a comment. If they roll back your rollback, flag it for moderator attention and walk away.

Answer (score 0):

If the questions is appropriate for the site, we should not vote to delete or close the question. And rollback an incorrect edit by the OP. If he/she rollback/edit it again, flag for moderators to lock the post. Also you can add comment to notify the OP that it is not appropriate to delete the question once you solved your problem.